# Array stockwell transform - tuple index out of range

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, signal-processing

i have constructed a matrix from a table of EEG signals and derived a array from the matrix. the array is of **shape(4097*100)** but when i am passing this array in array stockwell transform funtion, I get an error as: Tuple index out of range

```
#data1 = np.asarray(matrix)

matrix.shape (4097, 100)

tfr = tfr_array_stockwell(matrix,173)

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-78-abab5d5223f4> in <module>
      1 #data1 = np.asarray(matrix)
      2 
----> 3 tfr = tfr_array_stockwell(matrix,173)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mne/time_frequency/_stockwell.py in tfr_array_stockwell(data, sfreq, fmin, fmax, n_fft, width, decim, return_itc, n_jobs)
    170     """
    171     n_epochs, n_channels = data.shape[:2]
--> 172     n_out = data.shape[2] // decim + bool(data.shape[2] % decim)
    173     data, n_fft_, zero_pad = _check_input_st(data, n_fft)
    174
```

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's expecting (epochs, channels, time) respectively in a 3D array (you are providing a 2D array). Although the docstring says:

> The signal to transform. Any dimensionality supported as long as the last dimension is time.

... [the code](https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-python/blob/master/mne/time_frequency/_stockwell.py#L171-L172) seems to say otherwise.

I don't know enough about EEG data to say anything else, but maybe this gives you a clue to what's going on. If not, I would try doing:

```
tfr = tfr[None, :, :]
```

to add a single 'epoch' dimension (assuming time is in the last axis of `tfr` already).